# Counting blocks of numbers in parallel

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have 4 rows of numbers, the first is a block of 1-8.
The second row is blocks of 1-2, followed by rows of 1-3 and 1-4.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

The top row is the main row and a count will increment through 1-8 and then start again at 1. I need the other rows to keep looping back to the start until the end of the top row is reached.

So, at position 5, the second row should have looped back around to 1.

I have tried `2 - 5%2` for the second row (blocks of 2) - which works
but `3 - 4%3` does not work for the third row (blocks of 3).

What is a generic calculation for this?

Comment: Try `(4-1)%3 + 1` You may play with (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B((n-1)+mod+m)%2B1,++%7Bm,1,4%7D,+%7Bn,1,8%7D%5D)[wolfram]

Comment: I think that's it, it works for every number on every row. Thanks! I tried it out in the browsers JS console. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

On $3$rd row you have $$1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,\ldots$$.
Period is $3$, so you're right in considering remainders by $3$.
However the remainders were shifted by $1$. To fix this you just do:
$$(n-1)\%3 + 1$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation